# Derivative of $\text{Var}(a)$

Tags: calculus, statistics, summation, variance

Given that 
$$h(a) = (\mathbb E[a \bar X - \mu])^2 + \text{Var} (a \bar X).$$

I was asked to find the **first and second derivative** of the function $h(a)$ in respect to $a$.

I did break the function into multiple of pieces:
$$h(a) = f(g[a]) + z(a).$$

Thus, 
$$h'(a) = f'(g[a])g'(a) + z'(a).$$

I only have found the first part of the derivative $f'(g[a])g'(a)$, but I couldn't find the other part $z'(a)$. **What I am stuck on is the derivative of $\text{Var}(a)$.**

[image: What I have done so far]

Any hints?

Comment: This is fine we write $Var(a \bar{X}) = a^2 Var(\bar{X})$ then differentiate as usual.

Comment: But isn't the derivative needs to be in respect to a?

Comment: yes, so $\frac{d}{da} Var(a \bar{X}) = 2a Var(\bar{X})$

Comment: Ah I see. I was treating x.bar as a constant.

Comment: well it is a constant with respect to $a$. I've treated it as constant here.

Comment: Ohhh I see. May I ask how you get 2a instead of just a?

Comment: this is because $a^2$ differentiates to $2a$. I'm glad you asked. Always ask if you aren't sure.

Comment: Ah right. I forgot about that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: That also bring me to other questions that I may have. I think I have done the derivative for the first part wrong. Let me take a picture and post it on here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102211/discussion-between-tam-nguyen-and-george-dewhirst).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\textrm{Var}(X)=EX^2-(EX)^2.
$$
It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
h(a) 
&= ( E[a \overline{X} - \mu])^2 + \textrm{Var} (a \overline{X})\\
&= ( E[a \overline{X} - \mu])^2 + \textrm{Var}(a \overline{X} - \mu)\\
&= E([a \overline{X} - \mu]^2)\\
&= E(a^2\overline{X}^2+\mu^2-2a\mu\overline{X})\\
&= a^2E(\overline{X}^2)+\mu^2-2a\mu E(\overline{X})
\end{align}
$$
which implies that 
$$
h'(a)=2aE(\overline{X}^2)-2\mu E(\overline{X}).
$$

Comment: How did you subtract mu in the var() part of the second step?

Comment: Ah thanks a lot

Comment: @TamNguyen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties